# How to display response with proper spacing, line-break and formatting in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openai-api

I am taking response from OpenAi and store it using React UseState

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState();

try {
  const res = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', body, config)
  const completions = res.data.choices[0].text
  console.log(completions)
  setResponse(completions)
  setLoading(false)
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
  setLoading(false)
}
```

when i console the response it appears in this way
[image]

and when display using this code..

```
{loading ? (
        <div className='block p-2.5 h-full w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600  dark:text-white '>loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="block p-3 h-full w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600  dark:text-white " >
          {response}
        </div>
      )}
```

it will appears like this:
[image]

Comment: Instead of <div> , you should use ordered list for this purpose. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists_ordered.asp

But first of all, you need to be more precise about what is in the `TypeWriterEffect` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An div element does not parse spaces or carriage return. As a solution for your problem I recommend to use [`<pre>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) or to use css property [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.php) (`white-space: pre;`)

Comment: okay white-space is to display exactly data but what to use to store in database in exact same manner?

Comment: If you are happy with the default form of your string, save it as it is. I don't think you need extra encoding settings other than *text* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html) (for sql databases). UTF-8 collation is enough

Comment: im using firebase fireStore and when i store data in it will store and sum up all the things in one para.